# How can I solve a nonlinear ODE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear

How do I solve the following ODE in *Mathematica*?

```
DSolve[x''[t] + x[t]^2 + x[t] == 0, x[t], t]
```

Such that the answer is as shown:

[image: those commands are written in maple code]

Instead this function gives a `Solve[]` as answer, which cannot be evaluated.

How can I solve the highlighted area in *Mathematica*?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem in Mathematica / Wolfram Language? Clearly code in your screenshot is not written in WL.

Comment: many non-linear ode's do not have explicit solutions. Maple solution shown above is not explicit either. The solution is in terms of unevaluated integral. Mathematica solution is also implicit. If you look at chapter 2 of Kamke book, which is second order non-linear ODE's, you'll see many of them can't be solved by Maple nor by Mathematica. Look at equations numbered from 1591 to 1836.

Comment: I think a better focus for the question might be "How do I make use of the `Solve[..]` command returned as the solution?"

Comment: I do not understand the accumulation of down votes here. The code is given, the solution described, and an alternate solution from another CAS is given. `DSolve[]` gives a rather difficult-to-use solution. There is a good question here, even if the OP's focus, imho, is a bit off-target. (But when someone is asking a question about how best to use *Mathematica*, you have to expect that.)

Comment: Note if you eval the integral in the textbook solution with mathematica you get a nasty `EllipticF[ArcSin..]] ` expression similar to what `DSolve` yields.  You can convince yourself it is essentially the same solution in a different form.

Comment: also be aware the integration constants are not the same as in the textbook, `C[2]` ends up complex valued in the `NDsolve` result.

Answer (score 6):

As noted in the comments above,

```
s1 = DSolve[x''[t] + x[t]^2 + x[t] == 0, x[t], t]
```

yields an implicit solution in terms of `Solve`, which is a bit long to reproduce here.

However, an explicit solution can be obtained by

```
s2 = x[t] /. First[DSolve[x''[t] + x[t]^2 + x[t] == 0, x[t], t] // FullSimplify]

(* JacobiSN[Sqrt[(t + C[2])^2*(3 + 2*Root[-3*C[1] + 3*#1^2 + 2*#1^3 & , 2] + 
    4*Root[-3*C[1] + 3*#1^2 + 2*#1^3 & , 3])]/(2*Sqrt[3]), 
    (Root[-3*C[1] + 3*#1^2 + 2*#1^3 & , 2] - Root[-3*C[1] + 3*#1^2 + 2*#1^3 & , 3])/
    (Root[-3*C[1] + 3*#1^2 + 2*#1^3 & , 1] - Root[-3*C[1] + 3*#1^2 + 2*#1^3 & , 3])]^2*
    (Root[-3*C[1] + 3*#1^2 + 2*#1^3 & , 2] - Root[-3*C[1] + 3*#1^2 + 2*#1^3 & , 3]) + 
    Root[-3*C[1] + 3*#1^2 + 2*#1^3 & , 3] *)
```

(`First` merely eliminates an extra pair of curly brackets.)

Because it was surprising to me that `FullSimplify` would cause `Solve` to produce an answer, I plugged in a few numbers to lend credence to the explicit solution:

```
N[s2 /. {t -> 1, C[2] -> 0, C[1] -> 1}]
(* -0.888418 + 1.22386 I *)
(List @@ s1[[1]]) /. x[t] -> % /. {t -> 1, C[2] -> 0, C[1] -> 1}
(* {1. + 1.90609*10^-16 I, 1} *)
```

and

```
N[s2 /. {t -> 2, C[2] -> 0, C[1] -> 3}]
(* 4.14448 + 0.668597 I *)
(List @@ s1[[1]]) /. x[t] -> % /. {t -> 2, C[2] -> 0, C[1] -> 3}
(* {4. + 1.22513*10^-15 I, 4} *)
```

The two numerical results from `s2` thus satisfy `s1` to roundoff.  (`List @@ s1[[1]]` extracts the two sides of the equation contained in `Solve`.)

Incidentally, `s2//ToRadicals` can be used to eliminate the `Root` functions, if desired, but the resulting expression is far less compact.

Also, one might hope that

```
SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce];
DSolve[x''[t] + x[t]^2 + x[t] == 0, x[t], t]
```

would produce an explicit solution, but it does not.

Comment: The `FullSimplify` trick is surprising, but I guess it makes sense, since it does extra work on the equation.  Note that `DSolve[x''[t] + x[t]^2 + x[t] == 0, x, t] // FullSimplify` returns a solution in the form `x[t] -> ...` instead of `x -> Function[...]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Indeed, `Solve[s1[[1]] // FullSimplify, x[t]]` does produce an explicit answer too, although  `Solve[s1[[1]] // FullSimplify, x[t]] // FullSimplify` is needed (not surprisingly) to obtain the simpler expression in my answer.  By the way, what is the point you are making in your second sentence?  Thanks.

Comment: The `DSolve` call `sol = DSolve[..., x,..] // FullSimplify` asks for the solution in the form of a rule to replace `x` by a pure function, but it gives a rule to replace the expression `x[t]`. So `x'[t] /. sol`, `x[2.] /. sol` etc. would be left untransformed.

Comment: @MichaelE2  I misunderstood your comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Here's a marginally safe(?) way to trick it and get a pure function result: `Block[{Refine = FullSimplify}, DSolve[x''[t] + x[t]^2 + x[t] == 0, x, t]]`. Given the difference between `Refine` and simplifying, it's probably not a robust method.

Answer (score 3):

$$
x^{\prime\prime}+x^{2}+x=0
$$

$x\equiv x\left(  t\right)  $. Let $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$, hence $\frac{d^{2}%
x}{dt^{2}}=\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx}v$ and the ODE becomes

\begin{align*}
\frac{dv}{dx}v  & =-x^{2}-x\\
vdv  & =\left(  -x^{2}-x\right)  dx
\end{align*}

Integrating

\begin{align*}
\frac{v^{2}}{2}  & =-\frac{x^{3}}{3}-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+c_{0}\\
v^{2}  & =-\frac{2}{3}x^{3}-x^{2}+c_{1}
\end{align*}

Where $c_{2}=2c_{0}$. Hence

$$
v=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{2}{3}x^{3}-x^{2}+c_{1}}
$$

For the plus root, and since $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$ then

\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt}  & =\sqrt{-\frac{2}{3}x^{3}-x^{2}+c_{1}}=\sqrt{\frac
{-2x^{3}-9x^{2}+3c_{1}}{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\sqrt{-2x^{3}-9x^{2}+3c_{1}}\\
\frac{dx}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\sqrt{-2x^{3}-9x^{2}+c_{2}}}  & =dt
\end{align*}

Where $c_{2}=3c_{1}.$ Integrating

\begin{align*}
\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{-2x^{3}-9x^{2}+c_{2}}}  & =\int dt\\
\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{-2x^{3}-9x^{2}+c_{2}}}  & =t+c_{3}\\
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{-2x^{3}-9x^{2}+c_{2}}}  & =\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}t+c_{4}%
\end{align*}

Where $c_{4}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}c_{3}$ The integral $\int\frac{dx}
{\sqrt{-2x^{3}-9x^{2}+c_{2}}}$ can be evaluated in Mathematica giving

```
der = 1/Sqrt[-2 x^3 - 9 x^2 + c2];
mmaAnti = Integrate[der, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

setting the above equal to $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} t+c_4$ gives implicit solution of $x(t)$ with two constants of integrations. Same procedure for the negative sign. Hence the two solutions shown.

Answer (score 0):

Nasser's answer gives an explicit derivation. I write this answer to only note that a simpler formulation results if we use Weierstrass functions instead of Jacobi functions. (In general, elliptic integrals coming from cubics are more naturally expressed in the Weierstrass formulation.)

In particular, we have the solution

```
x[u_] := -6 WeierstrassP[u - C[2], {1/12, C[1]}] - 1/2
```

and we can easily verify that this satisfies the nonlinear ODE in the OP:

```
x''[t] + x[t]^2 + x[t] == 0 // FullSimplify
   True
```